# Mouse position and click detect in sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

```
int Game::MouseOnDot(float x, float y, RenderWindow &renderWindow) {
    Rect<int> Dot;
    Event event;
    Dot.left = x;
    Dot.top = y;
    Dot.width = 20;
    Dot.height = 20;
    while (renderWindow.pollEvent(event)) {
        float Mx = sf::Mouse::getPosition().x;
        float My = sf::Mouse::getPosition().y;
        if (event.type == Event::MouseButtonReleased&&Mx > x && Mx < Dot.height && My > y && My < Dot.width){
                return 1;
        }
            else
                return 0;
    }
}
```

I don't know why this won't work if the button is pressed on the dot it returns 1 which tell other function to close window. Am i doing something wrong on mouse position?

```
while (renderWindow.isOpen()) {
        processEvents(renderWindow);
        float Time = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        float TimeDifference = Time - LastUpdateTime;
        if (TimeDifference >= UpdateTime) {
            processEvents(renderWindow);
            y += 3;
            if (y <= 770) {
                if(Game::MouseOnDot(x, y, renderWindow)==1)
                                    renderWindow.close();
                Game::Spawn(renderWindow, Green_Dots, x, y);
                LastUpdateTime = Time;
                return;
```

Still don't work i paste here the part when MouseOnDot reutrns 0 or 1. It won't close the windows and i don't know why??

Answer (score 6):

Using 
*sf::Mouse::getPosition().x*
returns the position relative to the desktop, you if you want it relative to your renderWindow you need to do:
*sf::Mouse::getPosition(renderWindow).x*

then Attila is exactly right about the mouse/dot comparison :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you compare the position to the x coordinate and the height.  You need to compare to x and x+height (similarly for y coordinate/width)

Try:

```
if (event.type == Event::MouseButtonReleased && 
    Mx > x && Mx < x + Dot.height &&
    My > y && My < y + Dot.width) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: @Itsmeyxc - first, where is y coming from? -- are you sure you are entering the `if (y <= 770)` branch?  Second, whether `MouseOnDot()` returns 0 or 1 you are calling `Game::Spawn(renderWindow,...)` regardless as it is outside the `if` branch -- I assume the `Spawn()` will create a new window for you